# How to deploy a charm to a specific machine in Amulet?

Tags: juju

How can I deploy two charms to the same node in Amulet testing?

Comment: Why do you want to deploy two charms to the same node with an Amulet test?

Comment: Yeah if you could provide a use case it would help us understand what you're trying to do, thanks!

Comment: Well my charms are for a openstack-neutron plugin therefore i need to deploy all the openstack charms along with my own charms. In total thats like 13 charms to perform a test. I cant spin up 13 nodes for them right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case requires more than 1 machine, i.e. you are testing a service that must be stood up on a different machine from its dependent services:

On the machine you manage your infrastructure with juju:

```
sudo pip install juju-deployerizer
```

Export your environment, including the location of all services/units:

```
juju deployerizer --environment <your environment> --include-placement -o <your export file.yaml>
```

Edit your export file, make sure to follow the format specified in the docs: 
http://pythonhosted.org/juju-deployer/config.html#placement

Some things to note: only 0 is recognized as a machine Id. If your testing  environment calls for more than one machine: designate 1 service to be deployed without to: specification, then use that service name in the to: specification for all the other services/units needed on the new machine.

The default output of juju-deployerizer does not currently (05/2015) add the series information to the output, so just add it manually under the deployment name in your export file:

```
test:
    series: 'trusty'
    ...
```

Use the following to load your export file in the set up class method of your amulet test:

```
cls.deployment.load_bundle_file(bundle_file='<path to your export file.yaml>')
```

Proceed with the amulet tests as you normally would after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it done exactly that. You summed it up beautifully.